# open email with attachment

Tags: html, email

I'm trying to open an email with an attachment from my web page. All users have MS outlook and have access to the files I'm trying to attach. When I try it as follows it opens the email but doesn't attach anything

```
<a href='mailto:test1@test.com?Attachment="C:\test\test.txt"'>Attach to Email</a>
```

What could be the issue?

Thanks

Comment: That is not permitted!! Place the attachment in the application folder which the application user has access to.

Comment: @MarcusH If it's in the application folder could I attach it from the web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mailto links with attachments aren't possible. This would be a bit of a security hole if they were. You will have to include a link to the file somewhere else.

Chris Coyier does a good job of covering all possibilities of mailto links

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/mailto-links/